# Command for detecting whether the system is using a dark or light desktop theme?

Tags: command-line, x11, gnome, theme, appearance

There's [a way in browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) to query if the user prefers a dark or light theme so that a website developer could adapt the website's colours according to user preference.

Is there also a way to detect that on the command line? Is there a command that outputs `light` or `dark` (or some equivalent boolean-valued output indicating light or dark?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this command (tested on gnome desktop environment, ubuntu 22.04):

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme
```

It outputs :

```
'prefer-dark'
```

OR

```
'prefer-light'
```

Comment: OR 'default' :D

Answer (score 3):

I use the following command to detect the current color scheme, as I use a color scheme switching extension with Gnome:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# org.freedesktop.appearance color-scheme
#
# Indicates the system's preferred color scheme.
# Supported values are:
#
#   0: No preference
#   1: Prefer dark appearance
#   2: Prefer light appearance
#
# Unknown values should be treated as 0 (no preference).

scheme=$(
  gdbus call --session --timeout=1000 \
             --dest=org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop \
             --object-path /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop \
             --method org.freedesktop.portal.Settings.Read org.freedesktop.appearance color-scheme
)

case $scheme in
  ( '(<<uint32 1>>,)' ) exit 1;;
  ( '(<<uint32 2>>,)' ) exit 2;;
  ( *                 ) exit 0;;
esac
```

This works with Fedora 37 and Ubuntu 22.04 (running inside Fedora via distrobox, so YMMV).